# it is possible determinant of matrix(256*256) be infinite

Tags: matlab, matrix, artificial-intelligence, classification

i have (256*1) vectors of feature come from (16*16) of gray images. number of vectors is 550
when i compute Sample covariance of this vectors and compute covariance matrix determinant 
answer is inf

it is possible determinant of finite matrix with finite range (0:255) value be infinite or i mistake some where?

in fact i want classification with bayesian estimation , my distribution is gaussian and when
i compute determinant be inf and ultimate Answer(likelihood) is zero .

some part of my code:

```
Mean =  mean(dataSet,2);
MeanMatrix = Mean*ones(1,NoC);
Xc = double(dataSet)-MeanMatrix; % transform data to the origine
Sigma = (1/NoC) *Xc*Xc'; % calculate sample covariance matrix 
Parameters(i).M = Mean';
Parameters(i).C = Sigma;

likelihoods(i) = (1/(2*pi*sqrt(det(params(i).C)))) * (exp(-0.5 * (double(X)-params(i).M)' * inv(params(i).C) * (double(X)-params(i).M)));
```

variable i show my classes;
variable X show my feature vector;

Comment: Maybe you have overshot the floating point range? `256**256` is pretty big a number, and there are `256!` of those.

Answer (score 6):

Can the determinant of such matrix be infinite? No it cannot.

Can it evaluate as infinite? Yes definitely.

Here is an example of a matrix with a finite amount of elements, that are not too big, yet the determinant will rarely evaluate as a finite number:

```
det(rand(255)*255)
```

Comment: Here is another: det(5*eye(500))

Comment: perhaps matlab because the value is big and large estimate with inf is not?

Comment: @alikiani Indeed, too large values will be evaluated as `Inf`. You should compare your expected result (and any intermediate results) with `realmax` to see whether they are too large.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, probably what is happening is that you have too few datapoints to produce a full-rank covariance matrix.

For instance, if you have `N` examples, each with dimension `d`, and `N<d`, then your `d x d` covariance matrix will not be full rank and will have a determinant of zero.

In this case, a matrix inverse (precision matrix) does not exist. However, attempting to compute the determinant of the inverse (by taking `1/|X'*X|=1/0 -> \infty`) will produce an infinite value.

One way to get around this problem is to set the covariance to `X'*X+eps*eye(d)`, where `eps` is a small value. This technique corresponds to placing a weak prior distribution on elements of `X`.

Answer (score 0):

no it is not possible. it may be singular but taking elements a large value has will have a determinant value.